# Convert keyframes to JS and/or GSAP

Tags: css, gsap

I've spent far too long trying to get a CSS animation to work on MS Edge to ever warrant it's use but thought I'd ask here as it would be a nice thing to solve before I lose any more hair.

I have an SVG animated with CSS which works a treat in Chrome and Firefox which I animate it like this:

```
svg {
    stroke-dasharray: 187;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform-origin: center;
    animation: innerRotator 1.4s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

innerRotator looks like this:

```
@keyframes innerRotator {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 187;
    }
    50% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 46.75;
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 187;
        transform: rotate(450deg);
    }
}
```

I've tried and tried to figure this out so that it'll work on Edge and thought that GSAP might do the trick but my GSAP-foo is not strong and this is as far as I've managed to get... with poor results I might add.

```
var $spinner = $(".svg_spinner");
var tl = new TimelineLite();
tl.to($spinner, 0.7, {
    strokeDashoffset:46.75
}).to($spinner, 0.7, {
    strokeDashoffset:187
}).to($spinner, 0.7, {
    strokeDashoffset:46.75
});
```

Needless to say, it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for the comments :-)

A JSFiddle with my attempts so far is here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/64hv2328/ The innerRotator is the main issue as the outer one works a treat. I've replaced it with smil in the HTML which sort of works but isn't quite as smooth.

Comment: possible to share a codepen / jsfiddle?

Comment: Yep, like Tahir said, a codepen/jsfiddle would be super helpful. You might want to look at https://greensock.com/drawsvg (though it's not strictly necessary, it'd probably make things a lot easier). We've got dedicated forums for GSAP questions at https://greensock.com/forums/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had 2 issues:
1. You forgot to specify units for `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` which are required in Edge.
2. IE and Edge [do not support CSS transforms on SVG elements](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

Please look at the possible solution in the snippet below:

```css
.icon {
  display: block;
  animation: rotator .7s linear infinite;
  width: 65px !important;
  height: 65px !important;
  overflow: visible;
}

.icon circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 187px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: innerRotator 2.8s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rotator {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes innerRotator {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 187px;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 46.75px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 187px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="iconsvg icon">
    <circle class="svg_spinner" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" cx="32.5" cy="32.5" r="30"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent an age reverse engineering a JS solution and was just about to use that before you put this up. Much better to use CSS rather than JS in this instance so thank you very much!